# MongoDB caching in discord.js

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, discord, discord.js

I am developing my discord bot and it has joined alot of servers and one thing I have noticed is that any command that uses mongoDB became slow and I tried to research about this but there was no information about how to clear my mongoDB cache,Please help me.

Comment: So, basically, "I have a very vague and generic problem, please give me the exact solution, with all the fixes in the code I didn't show and the configuration I didn't provide"? Sure, give me a minute

Comment: Your question is off-topic and doesn't match any of the [Stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can't just come here and say "I have some problem, give me the solution". You are expected to give more information than that, explain the problem in detail, provide your code, etc. Not just "My DB is slow."

Answer (score 0):

Removes all cached query plans for a collection.

The method is only available from the plan cache object of a specific collection

```
db.collection.getPlanCache().clear()
```

For example, to clear the cache for the orders collection:

```
db.orders.getPlanCache().clear()
```

Check these links :

[PlanCache.clear()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/PlanCache.clear/#PlanCache.clear)

[PlanCache.clearPlansByQuery()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/PlanCache.clearPlansByQuery/#mongodb-method-PlanCache.clearPlansByQuery)